# Activate Visual Studio Community edition license for build server

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, license-key

I have a build server (Azure DevOps) which is trying to build an application with Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition, but I am getting this error:

> Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.7.7.
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.
>
> The license for Visual Studio has expired.
>
> The evaluation period for this product has ended.

Now I can log onto the server myself, run Visual Studio and I get the same error, but then I can click on "Check for updated license" and it takes me through the process of signing into my Microsoft account, 2 factor authentication, etc. and now I can use Visual Studio no problem.

However the build server can't. I am guessing I've only updated the license for my own user, not the user that the builds run under.

I've found this: [Automatically Apply license key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/automatically-apply-product-keys-when-deploying-visual-studio) on Microsoft's site which describes using StorePID - but it seems to need the product key and the MPC and as far as I can tell, Community Edition doesn't have a Product Key or MPC, though I'm happy to be corrected.

Is there an alternative way of activating the license (e.g. for all users, or for a specific user) or some command I can put into my build pipeline that will activate the license, so DevOps can use it too?